# Token based authentication in REST java

Tags: spring, rest, interceptor

I have a requirement that the user gets authenticated just once. When he enters the valid credentials for the first time, he gets a token. This token would be used to authenticate user for further requests.
Right now, I am generating the token after first validation and storing it in DB. I am also adding the token in the response header in REST CLIENT. In the spring interceptor class, in the pre-handle method I am checking whether the response contains any header with name token. If it contains, then the user will get the message that he is already authenticated. If it does not contain the token, then the control passes to the handler class and credentials are verified.
But this concept is not working, where I am doing wrong. If adding the token in response header is not the correct way, then how I check the presence of token for a particular user.

Comment: Why are you not using spring security ?

Comment: Can also use apache shiro, but if you use Spring maybe you can stick with Spring Security.